# Jenkins: Increase Parameter after successful build

Tags: jenkins

I am using to Jenkins to deploy versions as needed.
So I have build parameter eg

```
VERSION 0.0.1
```

If job is successful and 0.0.1 has been deployed the next time job will be run I manually change version ie

```
VERSION 0.0.2
```

Build again and repeat etc.
Is there a way to automatically increase this number after a successful build?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a post build script using the [Post Build Script plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin) which will update the version number and stores that in a file. Then you can access the version number in that file using the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) from your job.