# Way to change Jenkins' project variable value with script

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to change project variable values in Jenkins automatically when build is done?
In my case i got a variable VERSION, default value is 1. And i need to increment this default value every build done. Assuming build stars by cron in this case. Any plugins can help me?

Now i have something like this: [My build steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H92T.png).
It is a single working way to get project variable in my groovy script that i found. Now how can i set new value for variable? 
I read some similar question on SO, but didn't found a working way for me.

P.S. I can't use $BUILD_NUMBER var, because i need a possibility to set VERSION manually when i start build.

Comment: Similar question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087630/jenkins-increase-parameter-after-successful-build/

Comment: Missed that question. But i do not want use file or any external storage to save value. There is no way to change exaclty value in build configuration?

Answer (score 1):

First, of all, install the plugins [Global Variable String Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Variable+String+Parameter+Plugin) and [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin). Under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` you should now have a part, called `Global Properties`. There you add a new variable. In my tests, I called it `SOME_VER`.

[image]

At your job, you now add a Groovy postbuild part with this code adjusted to your variable:

```
import jenkins.*;
import jenkins.model.*;
import hudson.*;
import hudson.model.*;
import java.lang.*;

instance = Jenkins.getInstance();
globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties();
envVarsNodePropertyList = globalNodeProperties.getAll(hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.class);

envVars = null

if (envVarsNodePropertyList != null && envVarsNodePropertyList.size() > 0) 
{
    envVars = envVarsNodePropertyList.get(0).getEnvVars()

    String value = envVars.get("SOME_VER", "0")
    int NEW_VER = Integer.parseInt(value)
    NEW_VER = NEW_VER + 1

    envVars.override("SOME_VER", NEW_VER.toString());
}

instance.save()
```

Parts of this code are taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/KgCGuDmED1Q). This code does nothing else than retrieving the value of the global variable, change it and save the new value of the variable.