# Jenkins job to update another job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am new to Jenkins, I have a Jenkins job "job_a" with a boolean parameter "param_a" with default value set to "true", I would like to create another job "job_b" with boolean parameter "param_b". if "job_b" is executed, I want job_b to go and set param_a's (in job_a) default value to param_b's value, should I be using goovy for this purpose?
E.g:

I run job_b by setting "true" for param_b, this should go and update job_a's config.xml with `<defaultValue>true</defaultValue>` under param_a.

if I run job_b by setting "false" for param_b, this should go and update job_a's config.xml with `<defaultValue>false</defaultValue>` under param_a.

Would be great if a sample script is provided.

Comment: Can you please state the reason for -1?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the comment int this thread:
[Way to change Jenkins' project variable value with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164225/way-to-change-jenkins-project-variable-value-with-script)

Using global variables will help you with it.